# Why does Travis CI build when branch is pushed to remote?

Tags: travis-ci

I just set up Travis CI and I noticed that every time I push a branch to the remote repo, it kicks off a build. From my reading of the docs, this is not expected behavior...it should instead only kick off builds when a pull request is opened and on subsequent pushes to that branch.

Also, when I do open a pull request, it kicks off two builds, as shown in the
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsZU7.png).

What I want is the following:

1. push remote branch (Travis CI does nothing)
2. create PR (Travis CI kicks off 1 build)
3. push commit to the branch (Travis CI kicks off 1 build).

Does anyone know what additional configuration is required to achieve this result? Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The expected workflow can be achieved by disabling the "Build Pushes" feature as described here: https://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-03-05-repository-settings/

Comment: If you disable the "Build Pushes" Travis CI doesn't kick off builds when you push commits to the master, right? Is that ok?